# Store classes in extensions with SASS

Tags: html, sass

Let's see we have 2 boxes. We want purple border for one with 1px width, and we want red border with 2px width for the other one, but only if it shows on tablet.

SCSS:

```
.brd {
  border-style: solid;
  &-thin {
    border-width: 1px;
    &-purple {
      border-color: purple;
    }
    &-red {
      border-color: red;
    }
  }
  &-thick {
    border-width: 2px;
    &-purple {
      border-color: purple;
    }
    &-red {
      border-color: red;
    }
  }
  &-from-tablet {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      &-thin {
        border-width: 1px;
        &-purple {
          border-color: purple;
        }
        &-red {
          border-color: red;
        }
      }
      &-thick {
        border-width: 2px;
        &-purple {
          border-color: purple;
        }
        &-red {
          border-color: red;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

/*what I'd need*/

%colors {
  &-purple {
    border-color: purple;
  }
  &-red {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
%widths {
  &-thin {
    border-width: 1px;
    @extend %colors;
  }
  &-thick {
    border-width: 2px;
    @extend %colors;
  }
}
.brd {
  border-style: solid;
  @extend &widths;
  &-from-tablet {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      @extend &widths;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="brd-thin-purple"></div>
<div class="brd-from-tablet-thick-red"></div>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. The idea behind is to build a query at the class to set up the parameters as required.

I'm wondering if is it possible to store not just css key-value pairs in a "variable", but classes, and class extensions even nested as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with **SASS placeholders**. They are too limited. Instead use **mixins**:

```
@mixin brd-color {
  &-purple {
    color: purple;
  }

  &-red {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

And then reference it like: `@include brd-color;`